# Rest client with Spring RestTemplate and custom Object input parameter

Tags: spring, rest, resttemplate

This is my rest controller (server):

```
@RestController
public class RemoteController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.GET)  
    public Return serverTest(HttpServletRequest req, SearchFilter search) throws Exception{
        //...
        return new OutputTest();
    }
}
```

I want to write the corresponding client for this GET controller with SearchFilter object as input.

```
public void clientTest(){
        SearchFilter input=new SearchFilter();
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        HttpEntity<String> entity = input;// how to store SearchFilter input ??????
        ResponseEntity<OutputTest> response=restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/test", HttpMethod.GET, entity, OutputTest.class);
        OutputTest out=response.getBody();
}
```

How can I send a single object to restTemplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should tell Spring how to bind the request parameters to `SearchFilter`. There are multiple approachs to achieve that, The simplest solution is to use `ModelAttribute` annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.GET)  
public Return serverTest(HttpServletRequest req, @ModelAttribute SearchFilter search) throws Exception{
    //...
    return new OutputTest();
}
```

Supposing your `SearchFilter` looks like this:

```
public class SearchFilter {
    private String query;
    // other filters and getters and setters
}
```

If you fire a request to `/test?query=something`, the `SearchFilter` will be populated with the sent query parameter. In order to send this request with `RestTemplate`:

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

// prepare headers
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

// request without body, just headers
HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

ResponseEntity<OutputTest> response = template.exchange("http://localhost:8080/test?query=something", 
            HttpMethod.GET, 
            request, 
            OutputTest.class);
```

The other approach i can think of, is to implement a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` for resolving `SearchFilter` arguments. Also, you can break the `SearchFilter` apart and use multiple `RequestParam`s.

Comment: With this code I got "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing" from the RestController

Comment: Seems that GET must be bodyless, is it possibile? Converting it to POST method it works!! Anyway I have to use a filter object to handle this read request, what should I do to follow rest dictates?

Comment: You should tell spring to bind the request parameters into the `SearchFilter`. Simplest solution is to use `ModelAttribute` annotation. For one moment, i thought you're sending `POST` request

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. Is there something to to transform SearchFilter bean to queryParam string or may I build it manually?

Comment: For post requests, it can convert the request body but for get and query strings, i guess you should add them manually, at least as far as i know